# Fetch non-structured data in Synapse for Cosmos DB NoSQL?

Tags: sql, azure, powerbi, azure-cosmosdb, azure-synapse

We have a NoSQL Database in Azure Cosmos DB. We also have a Synapse connector to use this database with PowerBi.

This allows us to use a simple SQL script to fetch the data in PowerBi. Something like:

```
SELECT logs.Field1, logs.Field2 from logs
```

The data is mostly structured, but we recently added a new field (say Field3) to the new documents in cosmos.

But now, if we run this:

```
SELECT logs.Field1, logs.Field2, logs.Field3 from logs
```

We get an error saying that the column name is invalid.

How should we fetch this field using the SQL script in Power Bi? We want a NULL value when the document does not contain this new field.

In cosmos, we have the IS_DEFINED function built-in the SQL language, and we can use it to query unstructured data using SQL. But this does not work in the PowerBi query editor (I believe it is a Synapse problem). The error reads: IS_DEFINED is not a built in function.